# PHP add counter to name if already exists in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following multi-dimensional array and I need to iterate over it and wherever there is a duplicate name, a counter is added to the name.

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [clientName] => John Smith
                [clientType] => 0
                [clientDOB] => 1980-10-14
            )

     )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [clientName] => John Smith
                [clientType] => 0
                [clientDOB] => 1970-01-01
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [clientName] => Jeremy White
                [clientType] => 2
                [clientDOB] => 2015-08-19
            )

    )
```

The code I'm using is this :

```
$finalNames = array_map(function ($item) use (&$namesCount) {
    if (!isset($namesCount[$item['clientName']])) {
        $namesCount[$item['clientName']] = 0;
    }

    $namesCount[$item['clientName']]++;

    $item['clientName'] = $item['clientName'] . ' ' . $namesCount[$item['clientName']];

    return $item;
}, $arrayOfTravellers);

array_map(function($item, $key) use ($namesCount, &$finalNames) {
    $finalNames[$key]['clientName'] = $namesCount[$item['clientName']] == 1
        ? str_replace(' 1', '', $finalNames[$key]['clientName'])
        : $finalNames[$key]['clientName'];
}, $arrayOfNames, array_keys($arrayOfTravellers));
```

Which is returning a bunch of errors such as : 
Notice: Undefined index: clientName in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/europatours/functions/reportsFunctions.php on line 330

My assumption is that the code is not fit for a multi-dimensional array. Can anyone help please? I need to retain the complete structure of the array only where there is a duplicate name, a counter is added such as John Smith 1, John Smith 2 whereas Jeremy White remains without a counter.

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: please read [how do i ask a good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as your question doesn't show any effort

Comment: I'm just wondering why would you do that.. the persons names are not unique and should not be unique ever..

Comment: yes I did but the logic that I tried is idiotic and the code is embarrassing! LOL

Comment: any relation to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34221696/

Comment: @MateiMihai because the entity that needs to read this list will consider same name as the same person so they want a number behind every name which is the same.

Comment: Then it seems to be a bad design there.. you must use some IDs instead..

Comment: Not sure why you downvoted the question just because I asked a question. I didn't want to submit my code is because I'm still learning and the code I tried is crap but if you want, here it is : 

    $newArray = array();
    $nameCounter = 0;
    foreach($arrayOfNames as $row){
    
        if ($row['clientName'] == $row['clientName']) { $newArray= $newArray('clientName'=>$row.' ' +$nameCounter);
        $nameCounter++;
        
    }

Comment: Append it to your answer. Its hard to read code that long in the comment section. And.. appending the ID is not a good idea ,) This indicates a XY problem - http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @MateiMihai no, it's not...the names all have unique IDs in the DB. It's just that a printout list of the names to give to another company requires that names are numbered but 2 or more people have the same name so they don't think it's the same person. That's all

Comment: dont worry about crappy codes because at least we can take a look of it, its way better than no code

Comment: @Andrew Well, apparently posting crappy code will bring out the trolls instead of helpers and people calling you noob because of an xy problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arrayOfNames = array(
    array('clientName' => 'John'),
    array('clientName' => 'John'),
    array('clientName' => 'Mary'),
    array('clientName' => 'Mary'),
    array('clientName' => 'Mary'),
    array('clientName' => 'Tony'),
    array('clientName' => 'Alex')
);

$namesCount = array();

$finalNames = array_map(function ($item) use (&$namesCount) {
    if (!isset($namesCount[$item['clientName']])) {
        $namesCount[$item['clientName']] = 0;
    }

    $namesCount[$item['clientName']]++;

    $item['clientName'] = $item['clientName'] . ' ' . $namesCount[$item['clientName']];

    return $item;
}, $arrayOfNames);

array_map(function($item, $key) use ($namesCount, &$finalNames) {
    $finalNames[$key]['clientName'] = $namesCount[$item['clientName']] == 1
        ? str_replace(' 1', '', $finalNames[$key]['clientName'])
        : $finalNames[$key]['clientName'];
}, $arrayOfNames, array_keys($arrayOfNames));

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($finalNames);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(6) "John 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(6) "John 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(6) "Mary 1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(6) "Mary 2"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(6) "Mary 3"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(4) "Tony"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["clientName"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...those name are not duplicates shouldn't have a counter.

Comment: What do you mean? That was what I understood from the question.. The array of names have duplicates..

Comment: Now I understand what do you mean.. ok let me check

Comment: Look at the array I posted. There are non duplicates... Tony and Alex. In your code, tony and alex get 1 instead of nothing. Only the duplicates need to have the counter.

Comment: Thank you and apologies for the messy question but I had no idea how to explain myself properly, especially with the junk code I had.

Answer (score 0):

What about a combination of [array_column](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.array-column.php) and [in_array](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.in-array.php) when adding new values?

```
$records = array(); // your data
$name = 'John';

$i = 0;
do
{
    $newName = $name . ( ($i == 0)? '' : ' '.$i );
    $i++;
}
while (in_array($newName, array_column($records, 'clientName')));

$records[] = array('clientName' => $newName);
```

Due to performance issues you may want to call array_columns only once before the loop and store the results in a variable.